# lcov.info file in karma, angular not generating

Tags: angular, jasmine, sonarqube, karma-runner

I am running ng test in starter angular 10 project with code-coverage option. Coverage folder is generating properly, but i cant find lcov.info. I need this file for SonarQube.

Answer (score 21):

Go in `karma.conf.js` and add a type lcov in reporters
`reporters: [ { type: 'lcov' } ]`

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks a lot. My full path was `coverageReporter: { reporters: [ { type: 'lcov' }] }`